# Find customers in wrong level (hierarchical query)

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I'm trying to figure out, how to find customers which are mistakingly in wrong level.
For example so called "main customer" is in level 3 it cannot have "sub customers" in level 3 or above but in level 2 and 1 yes.
How to create such a hierarchical query which reveal this kind of mistakes?
Some sample, would be extremely nice and welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Without sample data and desired results, your question makes no sense.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Look this example:

### since first level open hierarchy, define level and leaf or parent. If your customer level = 3 and parent, he is found

```
    with tbl as (
select '12' id, null parent_id, 'main customer' status from dual
union all
select '13' id, null parent_id, 'main customer' status from dual
union all
select '131' id, 13 parent_id, 'main customer' status from dual
union all
select '121' id, 12 parent_id, 'main customer' status from dual
union all
select '1211' id, 121 parent_id, 'main customer' status from dual
union all
select '1212' id, 121 parent_id, 'main customer' status from dual
union all
select '12111' id, 1211 parent_id, 'main customer' status from dual
union all
select '12121' id, 1212 parent_id, 'main customer' status from dual)
select * from  
(select tbl.*, level lvl, connect_by_isleaf leaf 
from tbl
start with tbl.parent_id is null 
connect by prior id = parent_id) b 
where b.lvl = 3
AND b.status = 'main customer'
AND b.leaf = 0
```

output:

```
1211    121 main customer   3   0
1212    121 main customer   3   0
```